# How to add value to row by id sql

Tags: php, sql

I have two arrays with ID and description.

In database I have same ID but doesn't have description.

How I can add each description form array to current ID?

This is [full code](http://pastebin.com/6atkjuZa)

```
foreach($product->find('.block-d .btns-d .btn-buy') as $productId) {
    if(!empty($productId)) {
        dataId = $productId->{'data-offerid'};
    }
}

foreach($product->find('.description div div p') as $description) {
    if(!empty($description)) {
        $query = "UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = " . $description . " WHERE remote_id = " . $dataId . " ';";
        $sql = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    }
}
```

If I try to use just simple value without array it works. For example

```
$query = "UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = '1';";
```

Comment: what are your arrays? $description or $dataId

Comment: your UPDATE statement without the WHERE clause wil affect all rows in the table. you simply did not specify a condition.

Comment: @LucaJung $description and $dataid, for example in $dataID I have 1,2,3,4 id's

Comment: From another foreach which parsed by simplehtmldom

Comment: your description foreach put it inside your dataId foreach if condition

Comment: IMHO this is definitelly not good approach - why do you modify the data based on crawling the DOM? Reason one - would be slow, reason two - SQL injection risk,...

Comment: @HonzaRydrych, Because I'm parsing ID's and description from another site

Comment: I can attach full code, but it'll be very large(~50 strings)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6atkjuZa it's a full code, please, check it if you can @HonzaRydrych

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query is malformed. It doesn't have quotes around the description to indicate it is a string. For example, if the value for description is "stackoverflow" and the id is "1", your query would look like so:

```
UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = stackoverflow WHERE remote_id = 1 ';
```

So to fix this, the last quote should disappear and the value for description should be surrounded with quotes. Like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = '" . $description . "' WHERE remote_id = " . $dataId . ";
```

Also I recommend you to read [this article on SQL injection](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), as this query isn't safe.

Answer (score 1):

just use foreach and that`s all, try this:

```
$ids = [1,2,3];
$descriptions = [1,2,3];
foreach($ids as $key => $id) {
    $query = "UPDATE snowcore_parser_products SET description = " . $descriptions[$key] . " WHERE remote_id = " . $id . " ';";
    $sql = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
```

Comment: There's a risk of SQL Injection, use parameterized queries if any of that data comes from an end user.

Comment: I have foreach's for this. I'll update the question now